# Cannot update listview

Tags: listview, autohotkey

In my GUI I have a listview in which I want to change the value of a cell.  I've tried everything and everytime I call `lv_modify()` it returns `0` which means something was in error - which also means the change doesn't get made...

Here is my sample script - you should be able to run it just like this.  Right-click on an item in any of the listview controls and try to edit the text.  The messagebox reports the variables.

Where am I going wrong?

```
;-------- http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3656 ---
MODIFIED=20140531
Tabnumber:=1
gui, mainui:new, hwndmainui, ListViews On Tab2
gui,add, Tab2,  vTabnumber AltSubmit, one|two|three|four
gui,tab, one
gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview1 hwndlistview1 gListViewEvents -Readonly +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
LV_Add("", "bob", "harry")
LV_Add("", "first", "111111111")
gosub,width1
gui,tab, two
gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview2 hwndlistview2 gListViewEvents -Readonly +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
LV_Add("", "george", "harvey")
LV_Add("", "second", "222222")
gosub,width1
gui, tab, three
gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview3 hwndlistview3 gListViewEvents -Readonly +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
LV_Add("", "michael", "richard")
LV_Add("", "third", "33333333")
gosub,width1
gui, tab, four
gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview4 hwndlistview4 gListViewEvents -Readonly +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
LV_Add("", "harold", "marcel")
LV_Add("", "fourth", "44444")
gosub,width1
gui, show

RETURN

mainuiGuiclose:
exitapp

width1:
T1=70
T2=140
LV_ModifyCol(1,T1)
LV_ModifyCol(2,T2)
return


LISTVIEWEVENTS:
current_listview := a_guicontrol 
gui, mainui:listview, %current_listview%    

if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){ 
    LV_GetText(current_var, A_EventInfo, 1) 
    LV_GetText(current_val, A_EventInfo, 2)
    msgbox, %current_var% : %current_val%
}   
if(A_GuiEvent == "RightClick"){
    mousegetpos, mousex, mousey
    LV_GetText(current_var, A_EventInfo, 1) 
    LV_GetText(current_val, A_EventInfo, 2)
    current_row := A_EventInfo
    gosub, EDITListViewVALUE
}
RETURN

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDITListViewVALUE:  

gui, %current_listview%Editor:new
gui, +resize
gui, add, text, , Edit Value
gui, add, edit, w300 h50 -wrap r1 vnew_%current_listview%, %current_val% 
Gui, Font, S10 CPurple Bold
Gui, Add, Button,   x12 gListViewEditorACCEPT default, Accept
Gui, Add, Button,   x+4 gListViewEditorCANCEL, Cancel
Gui, Show, center, Data Editor
Return

ListViewEditorACCEPT:
gui, %current_listview%Editor:submit
;now assign the new value to it's matching variable
%current_var% := new_%current_listview%

msgbox % "Current Row=" . current_row . "`rListView=" . current_listview . "`rOld Value=" . current_val . "`rNew Value=" . new_%current_listview%

gui, mainui:listview, %current_listview%    
msgbox % "Success=" . lv_modify(current_row, "Col1", new_%current_listview%)    
Return

ListViewEditorCANCEL:
gui, %current_listview%Editor:cancel
Return
```

**[update]**

It looks like the access to the default listview is lost, despite the fact that 'gui, mainui:listview, %current_listview%' is called just before `lv_modify`.  But `lv_modify` works fine if not called in the `ListViewEditorACCEPT` sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah!  The trick was to reset the thread operation back to the main GUI.  When we opened the second GUI window, it took over the thread operation.

This goes at the tail end of the `ListViewEditorACCEPT` sub.

```
;Reset the thread operation to the main GUI
gui, mainui:default

;Now reset the default listview
gui, mainui:listview, %current_listview%
```